# Compute $\operatorname{Ext}^{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, limits-colimits

I know that  $\operatorname{Ext}^{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})=\prod_p({\widehat{\mathbb{Z}_p}/\mathbb{Z}})$. But the following steps took me a long time to figure out what was wrong with them. Can anyone check that for me? That will help a lot.

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Ext}^{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})&= \operatorname{Ext}^{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\underset{n}{\lim _{\longrightarrow}}\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})
\\&=\underset{n}{\lim _{\longleftarrow}}\operatorname{Ext}^{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\\
&=0
\end{aligned}$$

The second equality is based on the following conclusion: Given $\mathcal{C}=R-$Mod.

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(\lim _{\longrightarrow}A_i,B)&=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C^{op}}}\,(B,\lim _{\longleftarrow}A_i)\\ 
&=\lim _{\longleftarrow}\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C^{op}}}\,(B,A_i)\\
&=\lim _{\longleftarrow}\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}\,(A_i,B)
\end{aligned}$$

Note that Hom preserves limits, and direct limit in R-Mod is exact (used when take projective resolution).

Comment: Direct limits are exact but that doesn't mean that if a functor preserves them then so do its derived functors.

Comment: @EricWofsey In this situation, the reason is that cohomology does not commutes with inverse limit, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the biggest problem here.  There is also an issue stemming from the fact that a direct limit of projective modules may not be projective, though that can be avoided in this case by choosing your projective resolutions carefully.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks a lot! I still have a problem. I know how to choose projective resolution for direct limit, but colimit is left adjoint to diagonal functor, left adjoint of exact functor sends projective to projective, isn’t the diagonal functor exact? I don’t know why, it seems like $\Delta$ is just the copies of the original object.

Comment: The colimit functor sends projective objects in the *category of diagrams* to projective objects, but a diagram consisting of projective modules may not be projective in the category of diagrams.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, I get it. Forgive my carelessness. Thank you.